# K&R Exercise 1-14, stdin from the file

Tags: bash, stdin

Well, I'm getting my hands on `c` and have chosen "The C Programming Language" by colleague's recommendation. So far I'm in the chapter 1, so this is pretty noob question. Generally this is question for other exercises as well which I've came through.

I'm checking my solution on 1-14 with following [source](http://www.eng.uerj.br/~fariasol/disciplinas/LABPROG/C_language/Kernighan_and_Ritchie/solved-exercises/solved-exercises.html/krx114.html). And below the program listing I saw following note:

> Here's the output of the program when given its own source as input:

I only was able to execute compiled exercise and enter text manually and using `Ctrl + D` to emulate `EOF`. What is the ways to use input data from arbitrary file (eg. source) and make it work as author suggestion. I do assume that it is not copy/paste, at least not manual one.

What I've tried is `cat ./histogram.c > ./histogram`  but this did not work.

Comment: I think you need to compile this `histogram.c` - perhaps `gcc` would be handy

Comment: Try `./histogram < histogram.c`

Comment: A question has to be self-contained. Do not rely on external links, but post your code **in the question**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I've tried is `cat ./histogram.c > ./histogram` but this did not
>   work.

The `>` redirects output to a file `|` redirects it to another program, so you need `cat ./histogram.c | ./histogram`

Or (as Marc answer above) you can use `<` to read from a file into a program. `./histogram <  ./histogram.c`

edit: Yes I know this is really a question about the OS, or rather the shell, than 'C' but telling an obvious beginner to go away to bash.stackexchange.com isn't very helpful or making the *internet a better place*